# iTunes software service authentication error domain error 434

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, ios10, xcode8

I am uploading iPhone application using latest xCode 8. I have good internet connection and all the relevant settings set up at [iTunes connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/). My [distribution profiles](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisemanticcontentattribute/uisemanticcontentattributeforcelefttoright) are also set up correctly.

I am facing below error:-

> iTunes software service authentication error domain error 434

[image]

Comment: The iTunes servers often fail in many different ways for no apparent reason when you try to upload apps. Just try again and again.

Comment: @pkc456 Try to upload using Application Loader.

Comment: I, too, am facing this problem. I added a new developer to my team (as Admin) and they are experiencing the issue. I have a feeling it has to do with the changes propagating through Apple's servers because I can do the exact same steps.

Comment: fyi, related ; https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66014

Comment: I was facing the same problem, I tried again and it worked.

Comment: Removing the check boxes for app icon worked for me .

Comment: Just keep trying. My app validated on the fourth try.

Comment: I had faced the same issue many times. But nothing to worry about. Simply, trying again taken me to success.

Answer (score 17):

So this has what worked for me:

Preface: 
4 days of debugging, recreated certificates numerous times, nothing worked, every time i try to validate/upload via Xcode it says same error "iTunes software service authentication error domain error 434"

Solution without XCode:

1. Create archive in Xcode
2. Export IPA in Organiser (Xcode > window > Organiser)
3. Open Application Loader and manually choose IPA generated
4. Done

Solution with XCode:

1. Create archive in Xcode
2. Click Validate
3. Unselect BitCode
4. Check if its validated, mine got validated when i unchecked bitcode
5. Not Try to genrate similar fashion with Bitcode unselected
6. If all goes fine now generate with Bitcode Checked(mine worked with these exact steps)
7. Done

[image: This is in Organiser]

Comment: Solution with XCode works fine when I did the validation... thanks!  I'm using XCode 8.3.1 (for the record).

Comment: As I read this after I got the first error, I clicked "validate" a second time and waited for it to run...and it worked. I'm trying this next if the upload fails.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very common error while uploading a build to iTunes Connect.
A simple answer to it : "Just RETRY".

Comment: This should be the first step in any answer to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this error follow these methods.

1. If you have not added app icons add them and try archiving.
2. Remove developer account and add account again. Press `CMD + ,` to bring up preferences in Xcode and from accounts remove and add back account. Try archiving this.
3. Clean project (`CMD + Shift + K`), close Xcode, restart Xcode and
   build project (`CMD + B`). Check for warnings. ( if you are using
   cocapods some times Xcode asks you to change project settings in
   warning. Click on warning and fix it. Xcode fixes it automatically)
4. Simply retry archiving.

ToDo. Add More solutions

Comment: Number 3 worked for me. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was the virus protection software I am using. I turned it off before attempting validation and everything went fine.

Comment: What was the name of the AV?

Answer (score 1):

This could be the problem of Xcode. You can try two different approaches here.

i) Use Application loader, Download it. 
ii) Before using Application Loader please un-install all certificate and upload the ipa file. If it fails via app loader.

then second approach we can use try to upgrade the version of Xcode. Either de-grade it (xcode 7.X) or upgrade it (8.X) some time with some specific version of xcode and and specific version of OS system throw such error. 
Try using those hopefully second one can help you to upload the app.

Answer (score 1):

Change the network connection and application submit via Application Loader

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the device to Generic iOS Device before you archived the build? That appears to have fixed it for me on a couple of different occasions.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error response, read a bunch of posts like this that were uncertain of cause & solution, tried to validate it again with zero changes, and it validated successfully. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but it turned out I used a different profile in the Xcode project, then when I tried to validate the app. It wasn't noticeable since at my company we use multiple Apple id's under the same businessname. Maybe checking this helps?

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here worked for me but I was able to solve these errors executing the application on the device that is connected to the computer before archiving it. I tried to archive it again and the validate process was passed.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me. Following steps helped me fix it.

1. Quit the Xcode
2. Delete all provisioning profiles (/Library/MobileDevice)
3. Start the code and try to validate without download the provisioning profiles.

The xcode will download the profiles for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 2 builds in the same app and when I tried to verify one of them it started giving the same error. I removed both builds and re archive. It worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have checked iOS provisioning profile from developer website and found the one related to my app was invalid.

I have regenerated (all invalid) provisioning profiles and download it from xCode -> preferences -> accounts. This resolves my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different solution. I had "Enable Bitcode" set as false in my target settings but had "Include bitcode" checked as true for the validation. For obvious reasons, the validation would fail every time if I had include bitcode checked. I unchecked include bitcode and it worked just fine after cleaning my project.

Answer (score 0):

it is quite easy, quit and reopen the Xcode project clean the project change the build number and build an archive.it will work