# Xcode Validation Issue : iTunes software service authentication error domain error 434

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, xcode8

I am facing **iTunes software service authentication error domain error 434**

while validating. [image: Error what i am getting]

I know, there are more [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889093/itunes-software-service-authentication-error-domain-error-434) with this error. But no one has given correct solution for me. Though it may be apple server issue. But we need to figure out the solution as i am wasting lot of time for this.

Can anyone advise in this? And whether a firewall can make this issue?

Comment: Might be it's issue regarding to your network or firewall

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo I am also having the same doubt, i hope Firewall is making issue. But not sure. Let me try without firewall and update. Thanks

Comment: That does'nt helped :-(

Comment: Did you get at validation time ? if YES then ignore it and upload the App by AppLoader. It will be good.

Comment: Yes while validating only i am facing this issue, are you sure shall i ignore validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Application Loader.

Select **Xcode>Open Developer Tool>Application Loader** from the Xcode toolbar.

Worked first time for me after about 15 failed attempts with the method you've tried above!

Comment: Application loader worked for me. But the actual problem is with the network. I increased the Download/Upload speed, it worked

Comment: It seems that it's more reliable to use Application loader if you are not in U.S. I am using very fast network, but the speed of connection to AppStore server is very slow. In my case, only Application Loader can upload my app.